# printf() after popen(): strange behaviour

Tags: c

I don't understand the behaviour of using printf() after popen(). I have a folder with these 3 files:

1. middle.txt
2. test.app
3. test.c

**test.c** is the source code of **test.app**:

*test.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fpipe;
    char *command = "ls";
    char c = 0;
    char output[1000];

    fpipe = popen(command, "r");

    if (fpipe == 0)
    {
        perror("popen() error");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fread(&c, sizeof c, 1, fpipe))
    {
        strncat(output, &c, 1);
    }

    pclose(fpipe);

    char *position;
    char result[9];

    position = strstr(output, "test.app");

    if (position != NULL)
    {
        memcpy(result, position + 8, sizeof(result));
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("Output string: %s", result);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run **test.app** I obtain this ouput:

```
Output string: test.app test.c
```

Why not this?

```
Output string:
test.app
```

**EDIT**

Using suggestions from the comments I modified 3 lines (`position + 8` is a mistake from my original source code) with these:

```
char output[1000] = {0};
char result[9] = {0};
memcpy(result, position, sizeof(result));
```

but now this is the output:

```
Output string: test.app
middle.txt
test.app
test.c
```

Comment: You're using `strncat` on an uninitialized buffer, therefore you get UB. Initialize the buffer e.g with `char output[1000] = {0};` or with `output[0] = 0;`

Comment: @Jabberwocky: you're right, this was a very stupid error! Thank you

Comment: result isn't NUL terminated if you have too much data behind `position`. And `position +8` will point to the newline after "test.app"

Comment: `char output[1000] = {0};`, `char result[9] = {0};` and `memcpy(result, position, sizeof(result));`, this is the output: `Output string: test.app
middle.txt
test.app
test.c` (with a newline after the first test.app)

Comment: -1 for posting your solution in your question. Please post your solution as an answer to your own question. That is how SO really works. I will surely upvote this if you do that later. I am following this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified 3 lines (by opening post) with these:

```
char output[1000] = {0};
char result[9] = {0};
memcpy(result, position, sizeof(result) - 1);
```

and now this is the output:

```
Output string: test.app
```

1 Byte presents in **output** was responsible of this strange behaviour. We have to pay attention with the copied size, printed buffer must be a null-terminated string